# How does autosys job login into machine without any password

Tags: windows, jobs, autosys

I have an autosys job like :

```
insert_job: trial-backup   job_type: CMD
command: "E:\script\Backup.cmd"
machine: Windows45
owner: ellen 
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "22:00"
description: "backup job"
std_out_file: "E:\script\logs.doc"
std_err_file: "E:\script\errorlogs.doc"
alarm_if_fail: 1
timezone: US/EASTERN
application: trial
```

I don't give the password of user Ellen anywhere to my job. I wonder how the job is able to do its work? As in, what user does it login with on the windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

The owner that is specified to run the autosys job, has to be setup on the machine. Since your name would be the user on that machine it will work as it pulls your credentials from autosys_secure. If you will use a owner that does not have access to the machine it will fail with -655 error.